# The definition of the number of ends for a locally finite graph

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, geometric-group-theory

Here I am wonder what's the definition in terms of vector spaces over Z2, and how to show it's equivalent to other definitions.

Comment: You should add some context, like where did you see this definition mentioned?

Comment: For a locally finite connected graph, the space of ends is a much finer invariant than the number of ends. It can be any (Hausdorff) compact totally disconnected metrizable space (for a f.g. group it can only be $n\in\{0,1,2\}$ points or a Cantor set).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good reference for this material is Section 5 of the paper of Scott and Wall entitled "Topological Methods in Group Theory". Here is a link of a [scanned .pdf file](http://math.hunter.cuny.edu/olgak/scott_wall.pdf). Proposition 5.1 of that paper answers your question.